# C# File Modified Dates

Tags: c#, file

Is there an   **efficient**  way to monitor all the files in a directory and determine when they are modified? I'm trying to avoid polling the directory every couple of seconds and running:

```
File.GetLastAccessTime(string path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `FileSystemWatcher` class is all about.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [File System Watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137) - works great!